# Python-cgi display a .JPG file

Tags: python, html, image, cgi

I am trying to display a .JPG - File in Web-Browser, with XAMPP(apache)-Webserver.
Python 3.4 / Windows 8.1

The HTML-file has this link to the (python)-cgi file:

```
<form action="/xampp/htdocs/Python34/server_kontakt.cgi">
```

The Python-cgi file:

```
#!C:\Python34\python.exe

import cgi, cgitb, sys

def chk(element):
  global form
  if element in form:
      erg = form[element].value
  else:
      erg = ""
  return erg
d = open("log.txt","a")
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
s = str(form)
d.write(s)
d.close()
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<p>Ihre Daten wurden gesendet</p>")
data_uri = open(r'C:\xampp\cgi-bin\Python34\daten.jpg', 'rb')
           .read().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')

print(img_tag)

print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

The Problem is, when i want to show the cgi -file the browser shows only the python code 
or sometimes i get this message:

```
'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: I think you mean to `decode` it?

Comment: why not use a proper webserver?

Comment: i have no idea what to do know, how can i decode it?

Comment: would it make a difference to XAMPP?